# Unable to add a new skill on careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I’m unable to add a new skill on Careers, under the “Technologies” section.
I press edit, enter the new skill, press “Save” and nothing happens.

When the page is loaded, I see several errors in the console.
See the screenshot.
[image]

I’m using IE 11 on Windows 8.1 x64, all updates are installed.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: @ArieLitovsky, yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for reporting!

We had a `maxlength` attribute set to *120 characters* for both *Likes* as well as *Dislikes* under the *Technologies* section; even though in database the maximum supported character length is *300* for both of them. We have fixed the issue and added the maximum character length value(as *300 characters*) in the tooltip for reference.

Try adding the skills again and let us know if you still face any problem with that.